# Problem in creating diagram with ArcGIS Diagrammer 10.2

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-diagrammer, arcgis-data-model

I want to create diagram using ArcGIS Diagrammer .I use esri transportation Geodatabase as sample. when i import XML file of the sample,the links of the relationships do not show in ArcGIS Diagrammer.How can i show the relationships?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This the natural behaviour about relationship classes. It simply doesn't show the links. For example take a look at this video tutorial:

[Create Many to One Relationship](http://maps.esri.com/Diagrammer/createonetomanyrelationship.htm)

As a replacement, I highly recommend [Sparsx Enterprise Architecture.](http://www.sparxsystems.com/arcgis/).